# how to append text in Notes field using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to update the `Notes` field using the below script

```
Set-Group -Identity "DLName" -Notes "Comment" -ErrorAction Stop
```

The above script *replaces* the content of `Notes` if it has any content already. I want to append new data in Notes field. Please help me with this.

Comment: In case you arent aware of, you can mark your code sample and press CTRL+K or use the icon "{}" for code sample in order to mark your code, so its more readable.

Comment: Try `SetAdGroup DLName -Add @{info='comment'}`

Comment: Could you show us the error message or tell what is not working?

Comment: @Adis1102, it does not give any error. i want to know how to append the data in -Notes

Comment: @InzmamulHaq Ok, but according to Microsoft docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-group?view=exchange-ps) your code seems fine (Set-Group -Identity "Legal Department" -Universal -Notes "verified"), so if you execute the code it either works or throws an error

Comment: Above code works...But  what i need to do is, to append the new text in Notes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$group = Get-AdGroup "DLName" -Properties info
$notes = $group.info
$notes += " Comment"
Set-AdGroup $group -Replace @{info = $notes}
```

Bear in mind that Notes (LDAP attribute name *info*) is a single-valued attribute, so don't forget to add whitespaces or line breaks when appending values.

Comment: Thank you, i tried  this way already but was looking for something simpler.....I think i need to go with this way of appending the text

Comment: Doing it in one line as _Set-AdGroup "DLName" -Add @{info = "Comment"}_ would work if _info_ was a multi-valued atribute like  _otherTelephone_ attribute of user objects. Unfortunately, you have to get and preserve the current attiribute value first when modifying single-valued attributes.